# Some problems with php login

Tags: php, html, authentication, login-script

My problem is that I wanted to create a login screen, an registration form and lost password form. I managed to create an error message to the login screen but when implementing it into registration form, it failed to do so. 
So my question is, how can I add my registration form argument to function auth that it would do the same for the registration form?

```
case "authent":
auth();
break;

function auth (){
    global $myurl;
    $errors=array();
    $username="";
    $passwd="";
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!="") {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
    } else {
        $errors[]="Username missing!";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['passwd']) && $_POST['passwd']!="") {
        $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
    } else {
        $errors[]="Password missing, fill the blank!";  
    }

    if (empty($errors)){
        // no errors, check the information
        if ($username=="user" && $passwd=="password"){
            // correct information  
            header("Location: $myurl?mode=success");
        } else {
            // wrong information, back to login.html
            $errors[]="Vale info, proovi uuesti.";  
            include("view/login.html");
        }   
    } else {
        // errors with messages 
        include("view/login.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you include login.php page ? if there is any error then you are on the same page. just show the error(s).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, my plan is to make a pop-up for the errors anyways, this is just a temporary thing. Have you got any idea how to get the function to work for multiple cases?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    if($username == ''){
         $errrors[] = "Username missing!";
    }elseif($passwd == ''){]
         $errors[] = 'Password missing!';
    }
}
```

instead of this...

```
 if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!="") {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
} else {
    $errors[]="Username missing!";
}
if (isset($_POST['passwd']) && $_POST['passwd']!="") {
    $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
} else {
    $errors[]="Password missing, fill the blank!";  
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me or maybe I did something wrong... I'll post the full code: http://pastebin.com/nBVxVCVG

Comment: My goal is to make other pages post error messages too like the login.html page, but I cannot get that function to do so... Sorry for my bad English too!